# Django RSS-feed escaping €

Tags: python, django, rss, escaping

I've made a rss-feed in django and i wish to turn € into `&euro;`. I already use `|escape` to escape link tags and such. But somehow `|escape` doesn't work on €.

Does anybody now a way to also escape € ?

Comment: And why do you need to escape it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

€ is a perfectly valid utf-8 character.  You are almost certainly creating utf-8 output, therefore it doesn't need escaping.

Comment: ok, so i tried |safe wich should keep it from escaping but still i get ¬â‚ where i put €. My encoding=iso-8859-1 should i change that into utf-8 ?  i'm sorry if that's stupidtly easy but i'm very new to xml

Comment: i changed it to UTF-8 and it worked like a charm. i overlooked it a bit and was pretty logical. Thank you for the 'clue'.